# How Can I Combine This Functions in JS

Tags: javascript

It's increasing a form value of total votes on star rating. if click 1 star, increases votes +1, if click 5 stars, increases 5. How can i combine them?

```
    function incrementValue1() {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('ratecount').value, 10);
value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
value++;
    document.getElementById('ratecount').value = value;
}
function incrementValue2() {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('ratecount').value, 10);
value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
value+=2;
    document.getElementById('ratecount').value = value;
}
function incrementValue3() {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('ratecount').value, 10);
value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
value+=3;
    document.getElementById('ratecount').value = value;
}
function incrementValue4() {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('ratecount').value, 10);
value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
value+=4;
    document.getElementById('ratecount').value = value;
}
function incrementValue5() {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('ratecount').value, 10);
value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
value+=5;
    document.getElementById('ratecount').value = value;
}
```

Comment: If the only difference is the value being incremented, why not just pass that value to the function when calling it?  It sounds like you're just looking for some introductory tutorials on JavaScript and covering how functions work.  Tutorials are definitely your friend when learning a language/framework/technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a parameter to the function that indicates how much to increment the value.

```
function incrementValue(increment) {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('ratecount').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value += increment;
    document.getElementById('ratecount').value = value;
}
incrementValue(1);//increment by 1
incrementValue(5);//increment by 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the increment value as a parameter to one function like:

```
function incrementValue(amt) {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('ratecount').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value+=amt;
    document.getElementById('ratecount').value = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is take advantage of [parameters in functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions), which are data that is passed into the function when it is called. That data (parameter) is available as a local variable within the function.

In this case, you would pass the amount that you need to increment by because everything else in all those functions is the same:

```js
// You should get your element references just once, not
// everytime the function is called:
let rateCount = document.getElementById('ratecount');

// This function is declared in a way that makes it
// expect some data will be passed to it when it is
// invoked and that data will be accessible within
// the function using the parameter name defined
// by the function declaration (amount in this case)
function incrementValue(amount) {
  var value = parseInt(rateCount.value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value += amount; // Use the passed in amount
  rateCount.value = value;
}

incrementValue(16);
```

```html
<input id="ratecount">
```